# Wake screen after scheduled task wakes computer

Tags: windows, windows-8, scheduled-tasks, wake-up

Trying to create an alarm of sorts.

Task runs fine, computer wakes up from sleep fine, but the screen's black till there's user input.
Anyway I can get the screen to light up upon waking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**NirCmd**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)'s [*monitor on*](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/monitor.html) command should be able to help you out here.

Commands:

```
nircmd.exe monitor on
```

Comment: While downloading it says Virus detected??????

Comment: can you please update the Answer? is this valid command to run it via Windows scheduler? http://imgur.com/3eGVyyU

Comment: @YumYumYum: The files from the developer's site are clean. Read [this](http://www.nirsoft.net/false_positive_report.html) for info about false positives. Regarding the command, there are lots of examples on the first page I linked to above, but by your edit I see you managed to figure it out.